# Trying to trouble-shoot hovering a picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I set the content of function to "alert();", It recognizes when I hover the image. When I implement what I wants it do, which is hover another image over the original picture. Nothing happens? If anyone could some guidance I'd appreciate it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetNewImage() 
        {
           document.getElementById("thumbnail").src="images/art/thumbs/06010.jpg";
           
        }
        function SetOldImage()
        {
           document.getElementById("thumbnail").src="images/art/thumbs/05030.jpg";
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="thumbnail" onmouseover="SetNewImage()" onmouseout="SetOldImage()" src="images/art/thumbs/05030.jpg"  alt="Death of Marat" class="artThumb"/>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use document.getElement by id But id not founfd

```
<img id="thumbnail" onmouseover="SetNewImage()" onmouseout="SetOldImage()" src="images/art/thumbs/05030.jpg"  alt="Death of Marat" class="artThumb"/>
```

you can try this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetNewImage() 
        {
           document.getElementById("thumbnail").src="images/art/thumbs/06010.jpg";
           
        }
        function SetOldImage()
        {
           document.getElementById("thumbnail").src="images/art/thumbs/05030.jpg";
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="thumbnail" onmouseover="SetNewImage()" onmouseout="SetOldImage()" src="images/art/thumbs/05030.jpg"  alt="Death of Marat" class="artThumb"/>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`thumbnail` is a class, so you can do something like

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetNewImage() 
        {
           document.querySelector(".thumbnail").src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XCpHNOAzLqA/maxresdefault.jpg";
           
        }
        function SetOldImage()
        {
           document.querySelector(".thumbnail").src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.31a5d99ff4d1fac186599a7decd1cf85?rik=SpU2aqLepkVuuA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hickerphoto.com%2fimages%2f1024%2fpictures-f76t7426.jpg&ehk=SWYUsFxxPWF2LYjSRna6Yfukj3Ng60iCBzZ%2b%2buDP7g8%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0";
        }
        </script>
    <img class="thumbnail" onmouseover="SetNewImage()" onmouseout="SetOldImage()" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.31a5d99ff4d1fac186599a7decd1cf85?rik=SpU2aqLepkVuuA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hickerphoto.com%2fimages%2f1024%2fpictures-f76t7426.jpg&ehk=SWYUsFxxPWF2LYjSRna6Yfukj3Ng60iCBzZ%2b%2buDP7g8%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"  alt="Death of Marat" class="artThumb"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

try modify class to id, Class in the img and getelementbyid in JS